# Retornando Array[] com Obsevable

Tags: angularjs, angular, front-end, angular2-http

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Angular 2 e no meu service esstou retornando um `Observable<Pessoa[]>` mas ao retorna o  http com meu get ele corre o seguinte erro. `Type 'Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Pessoa[]>'.
  Type 'HttpResponse<Object>' is missing the following properties from type 'Pessoa[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.`

PessoaService

```
 /**CONSULTA TODAS AS PESSOAS CADASTRADAS */
getPessoas(): Observable<Pessoa[]> {
return this.http.get(this.baseUrlService, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

Comment: pq vc precisa do observe response??

Answer (score 0):

Se vc tiver usando o HttpClient faça assim:

```
getPessoas(): Observable<Pessoa[]> {
return this.http.get<Pessoa[]>(this.baseUrlService);
}
```